# How do I get my function to add the userName to the h2 tag

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am having trouble getting the function below to work correctly. The function is supposed to add the `userName` plus what is already in the `h2` header to the website after the user enters their name. It needs to show up as soon as the user enters their name.

```
/* 
 * this function will promtpt the user for their name; 
 * store name in a variable called userName.
 * Use variable called phrase, which will hold h2 content
 * Lastly write the "new" h2.
 */
function logIn() {
    var userName = prompt("Please enter name");
    pharse = document.getElementsByTagName('h2').innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll take a crack at this

```
// This solution depends on you having an id on your 'h2' element
var userName = prompt('Please enter name');
var headerElem = document.getElementById('yourIdHere');
var pharse = headerElem.innerHTML;

headerElem.innerHTML = pharse + ' ' + userName;
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for/if you want an explanation of why I did things the way I did!

Here's a working code pen you can play around with! http://codepen.io/csavage1994/pen/evvXoG

Comment: This did work for me. Thank you. We were suppose to use the getElementsByTagName for the class thought.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to accomplish this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mcwc66op/

HTML

```
<h2>
  H2 Text
</h2>
```

Javascript

```
var h = document.querySelector('h2');
var userName = prompt("Please enter name");
h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML + ' / ' + userName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += prompt("What is your name?");
```